# Including drift when estimating ARIMA model using fable package

Tags: r, arima, fable

I would like to estimate an ARIMA model (using the fable package), say ARIMA(1,1,0). How do I make R also to estimate the drift element?
To fit an ARIMA model, the code is

`DataSetName |> model(model.arima = ARIMA(TimeSeriasName ~  pdq(1,1,0))`

How do I add drift to this estimation?

`DataSetName |> model(model.arima = ARIMA(TimeSeriasName ~  pdq(1,1,0) + drift() )`

gives the error:"[1] could not find function "drift""

Many thanks!

Comment: Just for better readability, please enclose codes/code chunks in back ticks, e.g. \` _inline code here_ \` or \``` _code chunk here_ \```